# How to align text to image that is auto scaled with object-fit: contain

Tags: html, image, css, object-fit

I have a viewport that takes up about 75% of the screen and I fit single images of varying aspect ratios into it using the `object-fit: contain` css. Above the image I have text labels for the file name & type. I want to keep these aligned to start at the left most edge of the image and end at the right most edge. I could do this easily before by aligning them to the `<img>` tag.

One side effect of using `object-fit: contain` is that the `<img>` element is bigger than the viewable picture, so when I try to align text to the `<img>` it can appear that the text is floating off of the image.

How can I align the text to the viewable image, when the `img` tag is expanded to fit the whole viewport but the actual picture is autoscaled inside the `img` tag using `object-fit: contain`?

Comment: Since you're fitting the images inside a container, why don't you just align the label to the viewport/container?

Comment: That's what we did, but in order to dynamically auto-scale the image to the container without losing its aspect ratio we set `object-fit: contains` in the css which makes the `img` tag take up 100% width and 100% height of the container, but dynamically scales the actual picture within that `img` tag. So the element itself is taking up 100% width but the picture inside it isn't necessarily doing the same which leaves a weird hanging effect when the text is all the way out to the ends and the picture is only 75%-ish of the container wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very much dependent on markup, fixed widths and/or heights etc.

Assuming you don't know their width/height in advance, you'll need a script, as in below sample.

Updated: I added the `opacity` so the image and text display's at the same time.

*If you do know them, you still need to work out a bunch of CSS animation rules, covering their ratio and animation setting to make it look good, which can be done, though it will take some work. In the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36097410/2827823) is a sample how to set an element size based on the same way `fit-content` calculate size.*

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('.image-text').style.cssText = 'width: ' + e.target.width +'px; opacity: 1;';
})
```

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-wrap img {         /*  fit-content replacement  */
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.image-text {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-text">Some text we want to size and break at the same width as the image</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="some image here" />
</div>
```

---

Here is another post about getting an images both natural and scaled size:

- [object-fit: get resulting dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256745/object-fit-get-resulting-dimensions)